# Change custom post type url/slug in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

i want to change my custom post url/slug from "property" to "project".

From this https://ayanaproperties.com/property/chelsea-creek-development-sw6-london/
To this https://ayanaproperties.com/project/chelsea-creek-development-sw6-london/

what method/plugin or any function to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should search your theme for `register_post_type` function.
When you find it, make sure that it register your post type, and search for `rewrite` param. If it doesn't exists add it like the example below:

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'developer',
),
```

Then make sure that you have updated your permalink structure.